# Input directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, validation, input, directive

I made this input directive with ng-model and form validation

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('formInput', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: ['^form', 'ngModel'],
        scope: {
            value: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            var type = attrs.type || 'text',
                label = attrs.hasOwnProperty('label') ? '<label class="form__label" for="' + attrs.name + '_id">' + attrs.label + '</label>' : '',
                required = attrs.hasOwnProperty('required') ? 'required="required" ng-required="true"' : '',
                form = ctrl[0],
                newEl = label +
                    '<div class="form__input">' +
                        '<input type="' + type + '" id="' + attrs.name + '_id" name="' + attrs.name + '" ng-model="value" ' + required + '>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<span ng-show="' + form.$name + '.' + attrs.name + '.$error.required" class="help-block">Can\'t be blank</span>' +
                    '<p ng-show="' + form.$name + '.' + attrs.name + '.$invalid && !' + form.$name + '.' + attrs.name + '.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>';;

            element.html(newEl);
            $compile(element.contents())($scope);
        }
    };
}]);
```

but validation is not working, but if I remove this code:

```
        scope: {
            value: '=ngModel'
        },
```

then it will be everything alright, what is problem? I dont know how to fix it. Here is jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/axlpl/ytz7sb9y/3/

Comment: why do you try to set isolate scope when you use `ngModel` ?

Comment: im not trying to isolate scope (or I dont know :P ) im trying to learn angular, I need to get access outside "form-input" to value, and this is only way that I know

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hthy5dhw/